# Find parameters such that the sequence becomes a probability mass function

Tags: probability

Consider $(q^{|n|})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$  for $q \in \mathbb{R}$.
Now, I am trying to solve the following: 
For which parameters $q$ does there exist $c \in \mathbb{R}$ such that the sequence $(cq^{|n|})_{n \in \mathbb{Z}}$ becomes a probability mass function and what is $c$ in these cases?

What I notice is that we know that $n$ is an integer, which we can separate into two sums: $0,1,2,...$ and $-1,-2,-3,...$. Since we take the absolute value the second sum goes from $1$ to $\infty$. So the pmf probably consists of two sums that sum up to 1.

How do I now determine the needed parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sum of the terms of the sequence is

$$c\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty q^{|n|}=c\left(1+2\sum_{n=1}^\infty q^{|n|}\right)=c\left(1+2\frac{q}{1-q}\right)=c\frac{1+q}{1-q}$$

where, in the second step, we applied the formula for the sum of an infinite geometric series, which is only valid if the ratio is between $-1$ and $1$ (otherwise, the sum is infinite). Therefore, the values of $q$ that lead to a probability mass function are

$$|q|<1.$$

The value of $c$ is obtained by equating the sum to $1$:

$$c\frac{1+q}{1-q}=1 \implies c=\frac{1-q}{1+q}.$$